# Is there any python equivalent of google guava loading cache?

Tags: python-3.x, caching

I am looking for an in-memory loading cache which is compatible with python and provides specially these functionalities:

1. Time of reloading
2. Method of reloading
3. Thread safe

I found only in-built python libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You included the `guava` tag on your question, but Guava is a Java library, so it's almost certainly not relevant to what you need. I would suggest removing that tag.